# Manejo de archivos ts

Tags: ts

Alguien me podría ayudar con conceptos de menaje de archivos fiscos en ts, he buscado información pero en casi nula. La información sería como su alcance, objetivo, propósito.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.